# WebLogic failing starting the application - not able to find spring config file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, weblogic12c

I have the below defined in the web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:p360UiSpringConfig/p360UiDispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>p360UiDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Below is how my web-inf looks:

[image]

When I start my application in WebLogic I get the below error:

Error java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/p360UiDispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]

Question is when I have defined contextConfigLocation, why is it looking for the spring config file in Web-Inf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `contextConfigLocation` in the `web.xml` as follows.

**EDIT**

What is happening is The Spring container is trying to look for a context by `<Dispatcher Servlet Name>-servlet.xml` in WEB-INF folder. This is because you haven't specified the `<init-param>` for dispatcher servlet `p360UiDispatcherServlet`. `<context-param>` is used to specify common additional context paths such as DAO, Security etc. This should ideally fix your issue. Please check the modified `web.xml`

```
<!-- Any Common Additional Context Paths -->
<!--<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>-->

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>p360UiDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/p360UiSpringConfig/p360UiDispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```